# Get incomplete data when tring to add fibonacci terms to filename

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenames, fibonacci, os.path

I have this code about load_fib, write_fib, fib, and return_fib. I'm given a number n, and need to load last calculated fib sequence, and add n additional fibonacci terms to the filename, and return the last fibonacci number written on the file. I was wondering why I get `0` for data instead of `0 1 1 2` when trying `global_fib(3, filename)` and then `with open(filename, "r") as f: ... data = f.read()`.

```
fib_called = False
def global_fib(n, filename):
    global gf
    gf = load_fib(filename)
    i = 0
    write_fib(filename)
    while i < n:
        fib()
        write_fib(filename)
        i += 1
    return return_fib()

import os
def fib():
    global fib_called
    if len(gf) == 1:
        gf.append(1)
    else:
        gf.append(int(gf[-1] + gf[-2]))
    fib_called = not fib_called

def write_fib(filename):
    global fib_called
    if fib_called == True:
        filename.open('w')
        filename.write(str(gf[-1]) + ' ')
    fib_called = not fib_called

import os.path
def load_fib(filename):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        filename.open('r')
        content == filename.read()
        return list(content)
    else:
        f = open(filename,'w')
        f.write('0' + ' ')
        return [0]

def return_fib():
    return gf[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `load_fib` function, there is a typo when you assign the variable that contains the data of the file -

```
def load_fib(filename):
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        filename.open('r')
        content == filename.read() # <-- this line
        return list(content)
```

Should be changed from double equals (which is used to test for equality)

```
content == filename.read()
```

To single equals (assignment)

```
content = filename.read()
```

Comment: Thx! but I still got '0 ' instead of '0 1 1 2' for global_fib(3, filename). Do I need to modify the  else  part of load_fib as well?

Comment: Presently, in the `else` portion of the `load_fib` it appears that it just opens the file and writes a `0` followed by a blank. I suppose if there is another behavior, then yes it would need to be modified (i.e. put `continue` in place of the writing part ...)